# No module found Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As per code , when i tried to install keras it is telling already present, next line telling No module found keras.

code line 1:

```
!pip install keras
```

result :

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (2.7.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

2nd line of Code :

```
np.random.seed(30)
import random as rn
rn.seed(30)
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(30)
```

Error coming as :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-52c6b868b0a2> in <module>
      2 import random as rn
      3 rn.seed(30)
----> 4 from keras import backend as K
      5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 tf.set_random_seed(30)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Answer (score 0):

The module might not be on your `PATH`, which determines which modules can be accessed. To add it, run:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages:$PATH"
```

in your terminal. This command sets the `PATH` variable to the directory which `keras` is installed in, a `:`, and then the former contents of the `PATH` VARIABLE.